# Should i use separete css extensions when i use scss?

Tags: css, sass

I am new to css world.

I learned that there are properties in CSS which are nto displayed same on all browser.

For example if i want this css property

```
appearance: none;
```

to appear same on all browsers i need to use

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-ms-appearance: none;
-o-appearance: none;
```

for example - the `moz-` extensions is for Mozilla browser.

When i use `SASS`, should i write them, or this is handled automatically ?

Comment: if you are using npm for scss library , they usually handle them automatically for you

Comment: It depends really on your setup, which packages you are using for the compile and how do you set them up....

Comment: @Kerry how can i check if this is handled automatically ?

Comment: @SlavenTomac i use SASS in Angular which comes out of the box

Comment: if your setup uses https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer then it is automatically handled

Comment: @peckoski then most certain it adds it...maybe some realy-really-really new selector won't be added but most of them will be covered....there is .browserlintrc file in scope of the angular project which tells compiler for which browsers it needs to adjust CSS (and js)

Comment: @SlavenTomac Thank you. Where i can find this browserlintrc file in my angular project ?

Comment: If you've created the project with angular-cli it should be in the root of the project, .browserlintrc (notice it starts with a dot)